# How to fix my geom_text labels so that they fit inside the bars of my column chart?

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-text

I have the following `R` codes running in `RStudio`:

```
df2<-df1 %>%
  gather(year, value, X2016:X2019) %>%
  mutate(Mth = Mth %>% fct_rev() %>% fct_relevel('January')) %>%
  group_by(Mth) %>%
  mutate(y_pos = min(value) / 2)

df2$Mth <- as.character(df2$Mth)

df2$Mth <- factor(df2$Mth, levels=unique(df2$Mth))

df2$AsAt2 = factor(df2$AsAt, levels=c("D-150", "D-120", "D-90", "D-60", "D-30")) 

g1<-df2 %>% filter(value!=0)%>%
  ggplot(aes(
    x = Mth,
    y = value,
    fill = Mth,
    group = year
  )) +
  geom_col(
    position = position_dodge(.65),
    width = .5
  ) +
  geom_text(aes(
    y = value + max(value) * .03,
    label = round(value * 100) %>% str_c('%')
  ),
  position = position_dodge(.65), size=3.5
  ) +
  geom_text(aes(
    y = y_pos,
    label = str_remove(year, 'X')
  ),
  color = 'white',
  angle = 90,
  fontface = 'bold',
  position = position_dodge(0.65), size=3.5
  ) +
  scale_y_continuous(
    breaks = seq(0, .9, .1),
    labels = function(x) round(x * 100) %>% str_c('%')
  ) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c(
    rgb(47, 85, 151, maxColorValue = 255),
    rgb(255, 51, 51, maxColorValue = 255),
    rgb(84, 130, 53, maxColorValue = 255),
    rgb(244, 177, 131, maxColorValue = 255),
    rgb(112, 48, 160, maxColorValue = 255)

  )) +
  theme(
    plot.title = element_text(hjust = .5),
    panel.background = element_blank(),
    panel.grid.major.y = element_line(color = rgb(.9, .9, .9)),
    axis.ticks = element_blank(),
    legend.position = 'none'
  ) +
  xlab('') +
  ylab('') +
  ggtitle('January to May')


g1 + facet_grid(rows = vars(AsAt2))
```

The output is shown below:

[image: ouput]

My issue is that the Year labels inside the bar disappear in some cases. I have tried reducing the font size to 3.5 but I am getting the same issue.

Is there a way to ensure that the labels fit inside all the bars?

Note: I am also adding an extract of the `tibble` `df2`.

```
>df2

# A tibble: 100 x 6
# Groups:   Mth [5]
   Mth      AsAt  year  value y_pos AsAt2
   <fct>    <chr> <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <fct>
 1 January  D-150 X2016 0.26   0.12 D-150
 2 February D-150 X2016 0.25   0    D-150
 3 March    D-150 X2016 0.27   0    D-150
 4 April    D-150 X2016 0.290  0    D-150
 5 May      D-150 X2016 0.27   0    D-150
 6 January  D-120 X2016 0.38   0.12 D-120
 7 February D-120 X2016 0.25   0    D-120
 8 March    D-120 X2016 0.36   0    D-120
 9 April    D-120 X2016 0.35   0    D-120
10 May      D-120 X2016 0.31   0    D-120
```

Answer (score 0):

I will answer my own question here. I tried fiddling with the following codes:

```
df2<-df1 %>%
  gather(year, value, X2016:X2019) %>%
  mutate(Mth = Mth %>% fct_rev() %>% fct_relevel('January')) %>%
  group_by(Mth) %>%
  mutate(y_pos = min(value) / 2)
```

and replaced the last line with the following:

```
 mutate(y_pos = max(value) / 6.0)
```

The 6.0 was after some trial and error starting with 3.0.

[image: output]